# date time pass value from python to mysql

Tags: python, mysql, database, date

I kept having sql syntax error.. what am I missing in here in order to pull data by day.

Here's my python error :

```
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [MySQL][ODBC 5.1 Driver][mysqld-5.1.63rel13.4-log]You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%s and date_created < %s ,(start, next)' at line 11 (1064) (SQLExecDirectW)")
File "d:\sasdev\datax\program\py\global.py", line 33, in <module>
  """)
```

Here's the code :

```
start = datetime.date(2012,01,01)
next = start + datetime.date.resolution

while next <= datetime.date.today():
     print start, next 

     cur_ca.execute("""
             select id,
         date_created,
         data
         from bureau_inquiry where date_created >= %s and date_created < %s %(start, next)
         """)
     start = next
     next = start + datetime.date.resolution
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You execute a query with formatting parameters but never pass these in; the `% (start, next)` part goes *outside* of the SQL query:

```
cur_ca.execute("""
         select id,
     date_created,
     data
     from bureau_inquiry where date_created >= %s and date_created < %s
     """ % (start, next)
   )
```

You would be better off using SQL parameters however, so the database can prepare the query and reuse the query plan:

```
cur_ca.execute("""
         select id,
     date_created,
     data
     from bureau_inquiry where date_created >= ? and date_created < ?
     """, (start, next)
   )
```

PyODBC uses `?` for SQL parameters.