# How to pass date values to a sql query in python

Tags: python

```
import MySQLdb
```

I am actually trying to select `val` from `bars` using a where clause containing a id and a date. Is this syntax correct for passing date?

```
 def get_bars(foo_id,cr_date):
    cursor = mysql.cursor()
    cursor.execute("""select val from bars where foo_id = %s and cr_date = %s""", (foo_id, cr_date))
    row = cursor.fetchone()
```

Comment: Did you tried this code?

Comment: I think this link can give you the answer :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12535862/date-time-pass-value-from-python-to-mysql